# the_category if/else statement

Tags: categories

I need to do the following: The sense if I have a class `dportfolio` - show
a category `dportfolio`. Otherwise show usual category.

I use:

```
if ( class_exists( 'DPortfolio' ) ) {
      echo DPortfolio::instance()->dportfolio_get_category();
}; ?>
```

and when I try to add a second part of a code:

```
the_category(', ')
```

with `if/else` statement, I receive a php error.

Any suggestions to write this function in a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Is the code used inside of the loop? The following code should work:

```
if ( class_exists( 'DPortfolio' ) ) {
      echo DPortfolio::instance()->dportfolio_get_category();
}else{
    the_category();
    //or echo get_the_category();
}
```

If outside of the loop you can try `echo get_the_category( $post_id )` to show the categories.

Note: As you are getting an error, if you edit the question, include the full code snippet with `if/else` and include the error, then it's easier to help.

Comment: I use this code inside a loop. 
If I use your code, I receive this error: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in class-dportfolio.php on line 78". I receive this error in a posts loop and in a post single.

Comment: And on line 78, in class-dportfolio.php I have this function:
public function dportfolio_get_category() {
 global $post;
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'dportfolio_categories' );
 $content = '';
 foreach ($terms as $term) { //this is a line 78
  $content .= '<a href="'. $term->slug .'">'. $term->name .'</a>';
 }
 return $content;
}

Comment: Would you please paste your full class-dportfolio.php code in pastebin and send the link?

Comment: Thnx you very much! http://pastebin.com/Wp4Cypkx

Comment: First of all, are you sure the taxonomy name is dportfolio_categories? If yes, what do you see if you print $terms in line 76 and print the global $post in line 74? Like this: http://pastebin.com/fBuFFp0v

This will make sure if $terms is really an array.

Comment: Yes, the taxonomy name is dportfolio_categories. If I do the code from your example, I receive this, under the posts titles, where the categories should be displayed: http://pastebin.com/cKwyN6LH

Comment: This is the `$post` object. What's about `$terms` array at line 79?

Comment: Thnx a lot, I studied about terms and my code. All I can say is that I have these 3 files: http://pastebin.com/RrWgcD4X http://pastebin.com/nL3vL6j6 http://pastebin.com/h2LLgA0u and no ideas how to solve it. Very confused.

Comment: I used this function http://pastebin.com/6YzJp7a0 (on line 79 in class-dportfolio.php) and your code, but nothing.